# Is this a valid matrix circuit, I've drawn it based on guides and examples online

Tags: arduino, button, matrix

I'm trying to build a matrix of

- 6 toggle switches
- 6 momentary buttons
- 4 rotary encoders

I'm going to use a Pro Micro board and I'm wondering if my wiring looks okay, this is my first real electronics project so I'm very unsure and I would love some advice. If there's any more information I should add let me know and I will add it.

[image]

Comment: It might help if you used regular switch symbols. Blobs with pretty coloured wires attached don't quite convey the meaning as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, is there a list of general used symbols?

Comment: If you edit your post and click the schematic button on the toolbar it will pop up a CircuitLab schematic editor and you should be able to figure out the symbols there including diodes, LEDs, switches and pushbuttons. Double-click to edit to remove part numbers (but leaving the designators D1, D2, etc.). There's a Custom Component which you can use for the microcontroller or just use the NODE element. Hit Save and Insert to add it back into your post. We can then copy and edit it.

Comment: If you're going to sample the encoders, it needs to be fast enough to catch the fastest spin, otherwise you won't have valid direction information.  Not quite sure why you need more than 2 inputs and a ground on each one, but if you really do, you may want to post a link to them.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis what do you mean with "sample"? This is the rotary encoder (KY-040) http://domoticx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Rotary-encoder-module-KY-040-arduino-schema.png

Comment: A matrix system like this is "sampled" in the sense that you're not monitoring every switch at every time.  You "sample" them in sets of four periodically; depending on the switch and the polling rate, it's possible to miss a press and release if you're not looking at the switch while it's pressed.  You don't have to sample these, as it appears they only need 5V and ground, and the two output leads which you already have dedicated pins for.  I'm not even sure why it needs 5V unless it's doing some signal conditioning on its own; the ones I've used just have ground and pullups.

Comment: It does have a push functionality, so you can press on the encoder and it acts as a button. I'm guessing that's what the 5V is for? Would you say my schema is okay?

Comment: The rotary switch looks wrong with connections to 5V, 0V when they should only be a single column open or closed with array reading and therefore only use your 4x4 ports rather than 4x4+ 8 bits. or 16 ports all together  or something like that

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean.

Comment: post the rotary  switch datasheet in your question

Comment: @MiguelStevens, read this ... https://cb-electronics.com/products/ky-040/

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplexing 6 buttons 6 switches and the push switches of 4 encoders
That all looks good.

The encoder are all grounded and their signals go to individual pins, that's good too.

Presumably the pull ups on the encoder lines and the blue lines are internal to the Pro Micro

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question.

You will need to separate the switch and encoder grounds if you want to multiplex the encoder module switches.

You can add a second ground pin this way.
[image]
[image]